# Why is C# considered a statically-typed language, although it contains keywords such as `dynamic` and `var`?

Tags: c#, static-typing, dynamic

C# is considered a statically-typed language. However, it contains keywords such as:

- `var`, which infers the type at compile time, and
- `dynamic`, which determines the type at runtime.

Is this a contradiction?

Comment: Note that var infers the type in compile type. This is also available in Java, Kotlin, Scala and other languages. The type in this case is still 100% static.

Comment: What _actual_ issue are you trying to solve? If you don't like `dynamic` (which is understandable), just don't use it in your code.

Comment: How does `var` "contradict the principle"? If local variable type inference contradicts static typing, then global type inference *definitely* contradicts static typing, which means that Haskell is not statically typed. I question whether any definition of "static typing" which excludes Haskell is useful.

Comment: C API's in 'nix pass around void pointers all the time.  So there's a long history of statically typed languages occasionally using dynamically typed data by some means.

Comment: Not enough content for an answer: `var notAString = true;
notAString = "false"; // CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'` The type here cannot even be changed at compile time, let alone at run time.

Comment: "Statically typed" doesn't mean "you have to write the types explicitly". It means that types classify things that exist in the **source code**: variables and expressions. Dynamically typed means that types classify things that exist at runtime: values. There are hybrid systems where both kinds of types exist, and because there is a correspondence between code and runtime (there better be for a predictable system!), people will talk about the "type of a value" even in a purely static type system, or the "type of a variable/expression" even in a purely dynamic type system. But that is the core.

Comment: FWIW, the terminology around this is a disaster: 'dynamic typing' has no sensible definition, and is used variously to refer to un-typed objects, late-binding/dynamic dispatch (which is hugely popular in 'statically typed' languages), runtime-modifiable types (all dynamic features of languages), and more often than not is just used loosely to refer to the runtime behaviour of languages like python which I would argue has nothing to do with types. The term 'static typing' isn't much better.

Comment: Try doing `var x = 1; x="foo";` and you'll see why that doesn't stop it being statically typed

Comment: Can you give an example of a language that you do consider to be statically typed? Because even Haskell has things like `Typeable` and `Dynamic`.

Comment: worth noting that many statically-typed languages like c++, java and rust allow you to infer the type - c# is far from the only one with type inference

Comment: @VisualMelon fwiw imo for the most part "statically typed" and "dynamically typed" are *very* well defined - static typing means variables cannot change types (alternatively, that variables can only contain specific types); dynamic typing means they can

Comment: it's worth noting, at least in c#'s case, a) `dynamic` is quite a complex layer over the base language and b) i do belive it's rarely used, in no small part because every single operation performed on a `dynamic` object is a lot slower since you cannot use e.g. a dedicated instruction to add a number to another

Comment: Why is it that a car is considered a vehicle to transport you from point A to B, when it contains features that inhibit movement (brakes)? That's the question you're essentially asking.

Comment: “var” just saves me the effort of having to write down the type. It’s just as statically typed as if I wrote the type.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

C# has a static type system. So it is reasonable to describe it as a statically typed language. Just like any other OOP language, it also provides for some degree of dynamic typing. C# goes a lot further here than other statically typed languages by providing a `dynamic` static type, but this does not break its static type system.

Background:

With dynamic typing, values or objects have types. E.g. `1` is an int, and the result of evaluating `new Foo()` is an object of type `Foo`. We can think of every object being “tagged” with a type.

With static typing, expressions in our code can be assigned types. For example, `x + 1` might be an int, and the variable `foo` might be declared to only contain `Foo` instances. These static types are guarantees about the values that the expression might evaluate to. This is useful because it might detect potential bugs, before running the code. Or viewed another way: a static type system allows for basic proofs of correctness. Static type systems also enable interesting features such as method overloading.

A lot of time, the static type of an expression is obvious. We don't have to manually annotate every expression with its static type. The compiler has rules to infer static types itself. When declaring a variable, we can instruct the compiler to infer its type with the `var` keyword.

With statically typed OOP languages, we have both static and dynamic typing, due to the use of inheritance and interfaces. Now, the static types do not describe exactly what values are possible at runtime, but only constrain them. For example, we might define a variable `IFoo foo = ...`. This guarantees us statically that any object referred to by `foo` will conform with the `IFoo` interface, providing certain properties or methods. But we do not know which classes those objects might have exactly – we don't yet know their dynamic types.

C# has a unified inheritance hierarchy, with all objects being derived from the `System.Object` class. If we declare a variable with static type `Object`, then we can assign anything to it. However, we are only guaranteed that it will provide the methods that are part of the `Object` class, such as `ToString()`. If we want to call other methods that the object instance supports, we have to cast it to its actual type, which requires checking its dynamic type. We can do that via a cast. Casts let us write statically checked code dependent on the object's dynamic types, because casts can fail – the code can only be executed if the object really has the expected type.

A lot of code doesn't benefit that much from static type safety. As a shortcut for casting the object to the correct type before accessing a method or property, C# offers the `dynamic` type. This pseudy-type behaves differently from other static types, since it just defers any type checks to runtime. However, this is still perfectly safe. This cannot be used to violate the static types in other parts of the code, because the compiler will insert the suitable checks at runtime.

For example, consider a function that converts a dynamic object to an integer:

```cs
static int IntFromDynamic(dynamic o) => o;
```

This function is compiled roughly as if it were the following:

```cs
static int IntFromDynamic(Object o) => (int)o;
```

Neither variant would allow us to break the static type system, for example by trying to launder a string into an int: `IntFromDynamic("foo")` will fail at runtime.

Comment: @sanyassh No, Python has no method overloading in this sense that an expression `f(x)` might invoke *different* functions depending on the static type of `x`. What is possible: (1) You can annotate a function with multiple static type signatures using `typing.overload`. But these annotation have no effect on the program's behaviour. (2) You can have a function that inspects the dynamic types of its arguments and does different things depending on these types – allowing you to emulate overloading. The `functools.singledispatch` decorator implements a variant of this pattern.

Comment: `static int intFooFromDynamic(dynamic o) => o.Foo;` is valid code.

Comment: @Taemyr Correct, and if the value of `o` doesn't have a `Foo` property of type int you'll get an exception at runtime – all perfectly safe.

Comment: @amon _"all perfectly safe"_ - while it is still _memory safe_ and better than C-style UB or trampling over memory, a runtime exception caused by a _type unsafe_ program using `dynamic` is still a nasty surprise which can break a program, and I don't consider program-breaking exceptions "safe".

Comment: @Dai: Wait until you find out about the unsafe keyword. It's well named.

Comment: @Joshua `unsafe` is not really relevant to this QA though.

Comment: @Dai whilst "does what you expect or throws" is less safe than "does what you expect or is a type error", but there are a lot of things like that in C#, not just casts. And the "does what you expect or nasal daemons" is demarcated by `unsafe`

Comment: @Caleth The cast operator has exception-free alternatives: the `as` and `is T name` operators. But `dynamic` does not have an exception-free way to test if a member property or method name and overload is available or not.

Comment: @Dai my point is that "or throw" is still safe. The exception is caught *somewhere*, with well-defined semantics.

Comment: @Caleth _"The exception is caught somewhere"_ - the CLR does not make that guarantee. (And the CLR doesn't support checked exceptions either). In the CLR4.0, unhandled exceptions in an AppDomain or new `Thread` will (by default) cause the host process to die. People don't notice this because environments like WinForms, ASP.NET, WPF, etc install their own last-resort exception catchers.

Comment: @Dai Terminating the process is a well-defined semantic

Comment: @Caleth I think we're operating on different base assumptions about how software _should_ work...

Comment: @Dai I originally tried to avoid introducing that concept, but the essential property is *soundness*, not *safety* as in “memory-safe”. Some type systems are sound, some are not. An unsound type system allows us to subvert it, for example by having a variable declared with type `A` that actually contains an object of an unrelated type `B`. My point is that C#'s `dynamic` does not introduce such unsoundness, because dynamic→static transitions are checked at runtime. [Other aspects of C#'s type system such as arrays+variance+mutability are unsound, though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23968075).

Comment: @amon Thanks for great answer, and sorry for the late reply, because it really took time to understand it in details, as it is something completely new for me. So yes, `dynamic` is a type itself, and one of the available types, that works within the static typing system, but it is translated in a manner that it delays the type checking to the run time (compiler generates a new class and puts inside it the called methods, then checks if they are available), and suggests to the developer that it is a dynamic typing.

Comment: Great answer but I feel the `dynamic` example undercuts/oversimplifies the complexity somewhat. It gets decidedly more hairy when you use the dynamic object in an explicit way (instead of an implicit cast), e.g. `o.MyMethod(myFoo)` which cannot be easily converted to a static equivalent like the example given in this answer.

Answer (score 28):

C# is flexible and versatile language that is not 100% bound to a specific paradigm. At its core it is statically typed but also has dynamic features, as you have correctly noted. There is no contradiction here and no issue to solve.

Comment: This. Sometimes, the correct answers are just that simple - no need to search for some hidden reasons or conspiracy.

Comment: Saying it's not bound to a specific paradigm doesn't really answer the question. If it doesn't adhere to static typing only it can't just be called to have a static type system.

Comment: @JimmyT. Pay attention to semantics! Just because you _have_ something, doesn't mean that you don't _also have_ something else.

Comment: @R.Schmitz but it's about what it *is*, not what it *has*

Comment: @JimmyT. ...which can easily be based on what it _has_. A building can _be_ "guard-protected" because it _has_ guards patrolling, even though they don't patrol every single room. Suppose those rooms _have_ cameras, then the building _is_ also "secured by cameras".

Comment: @JimmyT. "Static typing" is just a label used to identify common traits between languages - not some cosmic law. As such, C# is statically typed, even if in some small respects it's _also_ dynamically typed.

Answer (score 16):

Per the comment, "var" just means "infer the static type as if I'd written it here". It compiles as if you'd written a specific type there.

Dynamic is a little different. Let's see what it says in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic):

> The dynamic type is a static type, but an object of type dynamic bypasses static type checking. In most cases, it functions like it has type object. At compile time, an element that is typed as dynamic is assumed to support any operation.

Look right there: "dynamic" is a static type!

That is, the precise type of the object is to be determined at runtime, but the *fact that it's dynamic* is recorded in the *static* type system.

[You can even see what this gets turned into in MSIL.](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) The method invocations against the dynamic object are done using reflection.

Comment: Basically interacting with a `dynamic` type generates MSIL that utilizes class reflection.

Comment: Sorry, but I think this is hairsplitting. From the POV of a dev who just uses the language the keyword `dynamic` allows dynamic typing (regardless of how it is implemented or that MS calls `dynamic` a static type).

Comment: Well, the question is hairsplitting; Rumien's "there is no contradiction" answer is also valid

Comment: Being able to call just any method on a variable without compile time error is what makes a dynamically typed language.

Comment: I opened the MSIL link, and I set the results to C# instead of IL, and I saw that the line `ExampleClass ec = new ExampleClass();` is kept the same, but the line `dynamic dynamic_ec = new ExampleClass();` was transformed to `object arg = new ExampleClass();`, Am I right?

Comment: @XY Yes, you're correct that that is the output from the decompiler. It's transformed into the "static" type "object"

Answer (score 2):

From a compiler/language theory perspective, you're confusing static/dynamic typing with implicit/explicit typing. Implicit typing is also called *type inference*.

In an explicitly typed language, the programmer has to explicitly declare the type of every variable. In an implicitly typed language, types can be inferred by the compiler. It is important to note that in principle implicit/explicit typing has nothing to do with static/dynamic typing. You can have the combinations: static/explicit, static/implicit, and dynamic/implicit.

The classic statically typed, explicitly typed language is C. Everything must be explicitly typed, and the compiler assumes nothing. Every variable definition looks something like:

```
typedef varname = r_value;
```

or for example:

```
char* x = "Hello, world";
int   y = 42;
int   z = 0; //Depends on which C standard you're using, but in general
             //0 is false and any nonzero value is true
```

A statically typed, implicitly typed language is Rust. The philosophy of Rust is to empower programmers, so while the static type system is strict, it also doesn't require you to be overly-explicit. Statements like:

```
let x = "Hello, world";
let y = 42;
let z = false;
```

are perfectly clear to the programmer and compiler, so they are implicitly typed. You can write them explicitly if you prefer or need to:

```
let x: &str = "Hello, world";
let y: u16  = 42;
let z: bool = false;
```

The two easy examples for dynamically typed, implicitly typed languages are Python or Javascript. In Python the principle is *duck-typing* - or, if it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it's a duck. In Python it is perfectly valid to write the following code:

```
x = "Hello, world";
x = 42;
x = false;
```

In a statically typed language, the type checker would error out on the second line, because once `x` is assigned a string type, it cannot hold a numeric value.

Note that there are some other topics that crop up here that can conflate the issue. Rust is statically typed, but it does allow redefinition of variables, so the result is that you can write code that looks like dynamically typed code, even though it's entirely static. In Rust, this code fails to compile with a type error:

```
let x = "Hello, world!";
x = 42;
```

However, also in Rust, this code does compile:

```
let x = "Hello, world!";
let x = 42;
```

The difference is the `let` keyword. This explicitly redeclares the variable `x` and when this happens the new version of `x` is allowed to have a different type from the old version. Both versions of `x` are statically typed at compile time, so while this isn't great coding style, it's technologically no more complex than declaring a new variable with any other name and doesn't require any special support.

Ultimately there is no clear answer about what kind of system is best. The choice can dramatically limit the kind of code you can write, and especially impacts the job of the compiler/runtime implementer. In particular, dynamically typed means that types are checked at runtime, at the point of evaluating expressions. For example, the following Python code runs without errors:

```
x = "five"
if isinstance(x, int):
    y = x + 1
```

This code runs just fine in Python, because the if statement is false and the following line never executes. (If it did execute, this program would throw a TypeError and stop running.) However, a statically typed language like Rust would choke and die at compile time on the third line at the type-checking stage, because `x` is a string and you can't add 1 to a string, regardless of the fact that later on a reachability analysis could show that this code never executes.

This has a lot of other knock-on effects as well. If you've ever wondered how an interpreted language could literally be 100 times slower than C or C++, typing plays a huge role. In Python, every single operation like `f() + g()` needs to run some code that verifies the types of the left and right operands and potentially does some dynamic typing as well. In C/C++/Rust, the static type checker already verified at compile time that f() and g() return the proper types, and could potentially implement `f() + g()` in as little as a single assembly instruction.

C# is very much an odd exception in that it allows both static and dynamic typing in the same language. First, note that `var` does not violate static typing- this is implicit typing. The type is decided by the compiler at compile time, and then that is enforced. However, `dynamic` definitely does violate static typing rules. It is made clear that the default and standard mode is static typing, with `dynamic` being used to add more flexibility in certain corner cases that are expected to be less common. Writing large parts of your program with `dynamic` is probably a good sign that you're doing something against the intention of the language designer.

Comment: The distinction between static/dynamic and implicit/explicit is a great thing for me, it removed a great part of the contribution, also the mention that you can have 3 combinations static/explicit, static/implicit, and dynamic/implicit.

I can say that your answer is the second correct answer for my question.

Answer (score -1):

All C# codebases use static typing, so C# is considered a mostly statically-typed language.

It also has support for optional dynamic typing, but many codebases don't use it.